# Why I only received first message in WebSocket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, nestjs

I have my client (React.js) - server (Nest.js) app. My goal is to use WebSocket for sending data from client to server, make some complex computations on the server side, send info about computation progress from server to client (in loop, after every iteration) and at the end, send final results to client.

My problem is, when I try to emit messages in loop, only first message is reveived by client. I simplify my code in order to check if I can emit messages in loop, but it still doesn't work.

Here's my client code:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

socket.emit('correlate', {
    formData
});

socket.on('correlate', (d) => {
   console.log(d); // Here only first message is logged
});
```

And my server code:

```
import {
    ConnectedSocket,
    MessageBody,
    SubscribeMessage,
    WebSocketGateway,
    WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import * as papa from 'papaparse';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import {AppService} from "./app.service";
import {HttpException} from "@nestjs/common";

@WebSocketGateway({
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    },
    maxHttpBufferSize: 500 * 1024 * 1024
})
export class EventsGateway {
    constructor(
        private readonly appService: AppService
    ) {
    }

    @WebSocketServer()
    server: Server;

    @SubscribeMessage('correlate')
    async correlate(@MessageBody() data: any, @ConnectedSocket() client) {
        for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
            client.emit('correlate', 'test' + i);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

My simple code now works, but the problem is, when I have my complex computations like that:

```
@SubscribeMessage('correlate')
        async correlate(@MessageBody() data: any, @ConnectedSocket() client) {
            for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
            // some complex, long computations, about 5s per iteration

            client.emit('correlate', 'test' + i);
        }
```

Messages are not emitted in real time, but client received them all after loop finished. What can I do to receive them in real time?

Comment: place the `socket.emit` call under the `socket.on`

Comment: Thank you, it helps, but now I have another problem with emiting in loop. I edited my question.

Comment: can you show us the code including the computations